# How to Fix Partial Results Appearing In Cinnamon (Lightbend Telemetry)

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am running akka cluster across three docker containers. I am running cinnamon to capture some telemetry, and I have this situation where It is only the Pool Size, Active Threads, Running Threads and Parallelism card in the Akka Dispatchers dashboard in Grafana that shows some data...the other cards in the other dashboards (Akka Actors, Akka cluster etc) are all empty.

The Akka Dispatchers dashboard page with some panel with data:

[image]

The Akka Actors dashboard with no data:

[image]

I am using the ElasticSearch Sandbox https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/sandbox/elastic-sandbox.html

It seems only the thread related information is getting through to Cinnamon, but nothing else: No information about Actors, Clusters, Routers etc

Any pointers on where to start troubleshooting such a sitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telemetry is a commercial product from Lightbend that includes support. So I'd definitely encourage you to open a ticket with Lightbend, the team there is very responsive. (Disclosure: I work for Lightbend, but I don't work in support.)

That said, it just sounds like you don't have any Actors configured for telemetry. Look at the docs for [Actor Configuration](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/instrumentations/akka/actors.html), for example. This is the example from the docs for how to specify which actors to collect telemetry for:

```
cinnamon.akka {
  actors {
    "com.example.a.A" {
      report-by = class
    }
    "com.example.a.b.*" {
      report-by = instance
    }
    "/user/x/y" {
      report-by = instance
    }
    "/user/x/y/*" {
      report-by = class
    }
  }
}
```

The same thing with other things you mention like clustering. You have to turn those on in the configuration. See the section "Cluster Metrics" in the Akka section where you will see this:

> Note: Cluster related metrics is turned off by default. To enable it,
>   you need to add these settings to your configuration:
>   “cinnamon.akka.cluster.shard-region-info = on”,
>   cinnamon.akka.cluster.node-metrics = on

But, again, reach out to Lightbend, they'll be happy to review your configuration.

David

Comment: Thank! I wonder how I skipped this part in the example projects I was using as guide. I updated the settings and everything is fine now!